# How can I improvise a refrigerator drawer handle?

Tags: kitchen

We can't afford  a new fridge. See below, half of the bin handle tore off. Manufacturer doesn't sell replacement bins for our 8 year old fridge. They said we must replace whole bin, not just the handle.

[image: Fridge storage bin with broken handle]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any furniture drawer pull that fits can be fastened to the front of the bin. You could even try to match ones already used for your kitchen drawers.

Here is a cup-shaped one with three screw fasteners, for example:

[image: cup-shaped drawer pull]

When you drill holes through the plastic bin for the drawer pull fasteners,
 put a wide stiff brace behind the screws
…
to make a 'sandwich' to reinforce the plastic which has become brittle.
Here is a 'cut-away' top view. The bin wall is shown in grey.

[image: Top view bin pull]

That's the structural part.

Aesthetically, you may wish to remove the jagged broken selvage for a neater appearance.
(I suggest using a very fine-tooth saw blade, be patient.)

Environmentally, you are conserving Earth's resources. Thank you.

Good luck

Comment: A good idea, but some of these bins are made of very brittle plastic, so I'd worry about it breaking when drilled. Any chance of using glue?

Comment: @StuartF Here's an opportunity to suggest your solution as an answer rather than a comment. Be as detailed and specific as you can. The photo will help you. Often, there is no picture to use.

Comment: I'm not sure what glue would work in a refrigerator, since it has to handle cold but be safe to use around food.

Answer (score 2):

You can either

- Add a handle by making two small holes and thread a piece of rope through or
- Cut a grip hole either as a notch at the top or a full hole a bit lower, large enough to comfortably grip the drawer.

The former leaves the drawer structurally whole, but depending on material the rope can be a problem when cleaning and potentially harbor mold, the latter weakens the drawer more and you need to ensure the remainder is stable enough even with a fully loaded drawer.

Depending on how brittle the material is, I would either drill/saw or melt the required holes. Use the broken off bit to experiment.

Long-term, acquiring a new drawer is probably the best option. Consider also second hand sources.